# Initialize model object and check validity before saving to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to initialize a model object like:

```
@review = current_user.reviews.build(params[:review])
```

and then check it's validity against the validation rules in review.rb?

...without attempting to save the model object to the DB??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@review.valid?` to check if the model is valid without saving it to the database.

```
if @review.valid?
  #Do something
end
```

PS: In fact you can add validations to any class without having to use database functionality by using [`ActiveModel::Validations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html). See [Railscast #219](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) for an example.